# I am trying to create an array and fill it with numbers from 1 to 10. Why it doesn't work?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create an array and fill it with numbers from 1 to 10. Why it doesn't work? After filling it all the numbers should be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()  { 
        int i;
        int number[10];



        for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {

            printf("%d\n",number[i]);

        }
        printf("\n");



        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you filling it? Also array indices start at 0, not 1

Comment: You never filled in the array.  You'd need something like `number[i] = i`

Answer (score 4):

In C this first index is 0. Therefore the code should use indexes 0 through to 9

I.e.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()  { 
        int i;
        int number[10];
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
          number[i] = 1 + i;
          printf("%d\n",number[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
       return 0;
    }
```